# Is there any way to access ViewComposer variable in controller

Tags: laravel

I have following composer. and I want to access `$myId` every action of controller in my application. How do I achieve this? any help would be great.

```
class DistributorComposer {

    /**
     * Create a new Category composer.
     *
     * @param  $menuStr
     * @return void
     */
    // Global Variables for menu
    var $menuStr = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function compose(View $view) {
        //$data['language'] = FrontendController::getDistributorInfo();
        $view->with('myId',Input::get('d_id'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this while assigning - `\App::instance('myId', $myId);`

And this while retrieving - `$myId = \App('myId');`

Comment: hello, It says "Class myId does not exist"

Comment: Hi...thanx for yout quick reply Actually when I put Simple Exit in composer function it doesn't , May be composer is not loading?  I have registered by "View::composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\DistributorComposer');

Comment: use dd inside the composer file to check if it is getting executed

Comment: yes.. It is not executing..thats why I am getting this error.

Comment: Let me get this you want to assign a parameter which can be accessible from any view right? If it is than simply make and call a new middleware and add the assigning code in handle function inside middleware

Comment: I want to assign parameter which can be accessible in all controllers of application. basically I want  id as soon as application loads. on the basis of that id all function of controllers will work

Comment: you can use middleware for this

Comment: Thank You.. I have achieved it by middleware